# Eclipse not reading JSON file

Tags: java, eclipse, json

I'm trying to run a java class that reads off some values from a JSON file. When I run it, however, I get the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \file001.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jsonPractice.main(jsonPractice.java:21)
```

The code I am using is:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class jsonPractice {


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try
            {
                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file001.json"));
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                System.out.println(name);

                long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
                System.out.println(age);

                JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
                Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println(iterator.next());
                }
            }
              catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I've made sure to add the json jar to the build path and the file001.json is located inside the folder in the workspace for the project.

Thanks

Comment: You'll also want to close that FileReader() or else your process will leave a file descriptor open.  try {...} finally { reader.close(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current directory using -

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Let's consider your file is in `/home/user/test/file/file001.json` and you are getting `/home/user/test/` using the current directory command(s). Then, append the rest `file/file001.json` like -

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(currentDir + "file/file001.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest thing to do here would be to use the full path of the file:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/the/full/path/file001.json"));
```